# Adding shorthand JS to a parent

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I'm creating some shorthand js variables, which ultimately will be merged into the parent to create some XML.  What am I doing wrong here with my shorthand js?  I'm a little lost.

I came up with this brief example to outline my issue:

```
function testing() {
  var attachments = [];

  var attachment1 = [ "attachment" ,
                     [ "name", "myname1" ],
                     [ "type", "mytype1" ]
                    ];
  attachments.push(attachment1);
  var attachment2 = [ "attachment" ,
                     [ "name", "myname2" ],
                     [ "type", "mytype2" ]
                    ];
  attachments.push(attachment2);

  var email = [ "email",
               [ "subject", "mySubject"],
               [ "body", "myBody"],
               [ "attachments", attachments ]
              ];
  Logger.log(Xml.parseJS(email).toXmlString());
}
```

Log output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<email>
    <subject>mySubject</subject>
    <body>myBody</body>
    <attachments>[Ljava.lang.Object;@b06f679</attachments>
</email>
```

Ideally, it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<email>
    <subject>mySubject</subject>
    <body>myBody</body>
    <attachments>
        <attachment>
            <name>myname1</name>
            <type>mytype1</type>
        </attachment>
        <attachment>
            <name>myname2</name>
            <type>mytype2</type>
        </attachment>
    </attachments>
</email>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are putting an array inside of an array.

```
var attachment1 = [ "attachment" ,
                   [ "name", "myname1" ],
                   [ "type", "mytype1" ]
                  ];

var attachment2 = [ "attachment" ,
                   [ "name", "myname2" ],
                   [ "type", "mytype2" ]
                  ];


var email = [ "email",
             [ "subject", "mySubject"],
             [ "body", "myBody"],
             [ "attachments"]
            ];
email[3].push(attachment1);
email[3].push(attachment2);
```

You can use console.log(email) to see the different in the structures the web browser

This will also the same thing is more readable

```
attachments = ["attachments"];
attachments.push(attachment1);
attachments.push(attachment2);
var email = [ "email",
              [ "subject", "mySubject"],
              [ "body", "myBody"],
              attachments
            ];
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line:

```
[ "attachments", attachments ]
```

What this effectively does is:

```
[ "attachments", [ [attachment1], [attachment2] ] ]
```

while the correct should be:

```
[ "attachments", [attachment1], [attachment2] ]
```

One solution would be:

```
var email = [ "email",
              [ "subject", "mySubject"],
              [ "body", "myBody"],
              [ "attachments", attachment1, attachment2 ]   //<-- The attachment row must have two childs not one. 
            ];
```

Alternatively you can initialize the attachments array as follows:

```
var attachments = ['attachments']
```

Then push the attachments as in your test code above.
Finally the e-mail would be:

```
var email = [ "email",
              [ "subject", "mySubject"],
              [ "body", "myBody"],
              attachments
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the [E4X extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML) to create an XML in GAS. Here is an example. The both `getOrgXML` and `createXMLFromCode` function create the same XML string.

```
function getOrgXML() {
  var xml = <email>
    <subject>mySubject</subject>
    <body>myBody</body>
    <attachments>
        <attachment>
            <name>myname1</name>
            <type>mytype1</type>
        </attachment>
        <attachment>
            <name>myname2</name>
            <type>mytype2</type>
        </attachment>
    </attachments>
  </email>;
  return xml;
}

function createXMLFromCode() {
  var attachment = <attachment/>;
  attachment.name = '';
  attachment.type = '';
  var email = <email/>;
  email.subject = 'mySubject';
  email.body = 'myBody';
  email.attachments = <attachments/>;
  var attach1 = attachment.copy();
  attach1.name = 'myname1';
  attach1.type = 'mytype1';
  var attach2 = attachment.copy();
  attach2.name = 'myname2';
  attach2.type = 'mytype2';
  email.attachments.appendChild(attach1);
  email.attachments.appendChild(attach2);
  return email;
}

function testXML() {
  var areEqual = getOrgXML().toXMLString() == createXMLFromCode().toXMLString();
  return areEqual;
}
```